# snmp-get value from pass is missing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, snmp

I want to read a GPIO-pin of a RaspberryPi via snmp. I wrote a script in python to read the pin. For testing purposes I delivered the value 17 and 99.

`/usr/local/bin/snmp-gpio17.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -u
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
if not GPIO.input(17):
   var=17
else:
   var=99
print ( var )
```

This script is called by  `/usr/local/bin/snmp-gpio17.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "-g" ]
then
echo .1.3.6.1.4.1.18565.1.12.101.1.17
echo gauge
python /usr/local/bin/snmp-gpio17.py
fi
exit 0
```

In `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`, I added the line

```
pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.18565.1.12.101.1.17 /bin/sh  /usr/local/bin/snmp-gpio17.sh
```

When I run the script on the RasPi it works:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# /usr/local/bin/snmp-gpio17.sh -g
.1.3.6.1.4.1.18565.1.12.101.1.17
gauge
17
```

but when I try to read the OID (locally or over the network) I get:

```
karls@mintbox ~ $ snmpget -v1 -c public 192.168.129.4 .1.3.6.1.4.1.18565.1.12.101.1.17
iso.3.6.1.4.1.18565.1.12.101.1.17 = Gauge32: 0
```

I also set up measurement of the cpu-temperature via snmp with another pass-line and it works fine. I use nearly the same script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "-g" ]
then
echo .1.3.6.1.4.1.18565.1.12.101.1.101
echo gauge
cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
fi
exit 0
```

So the snmp-communication seems to be OK (I compared answers with wireshark), but snmpd on the RasPi gets wrong information from the bash-script.

Anyone have an idea?

Regards, Karl

Comment: As a side note, use `#/bin/bash -e` in production scripts so they quit instantly when there's an error rather than running amok.

Comment: Thank you ivan.  Now I think, it must be a problem of user-righths. When I use snmp (locally or remotely) the shell-script runs, the python-script too, but the script cannot read the gpio-pins :-(   I put user "snmp" in group "gpio", but it does not help.

Comment: [solved] It works now, even if I remove user snmp from group gpio. My problem in testing was, that I did not wait between two tests. I found out, that snmpd on the RasPi caches the result of a get for 30 seconds. Only if you wait that long, you get the new result! Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

[solved] It works now, even if I remove user snmp from group gpio. My problem in testing was, that I did not wait between two tests. I found out, that snmpd on the RasPi caches the result of a get for 30 seconds. Only if you wait that long, you get the new result! Thanks to all